# #wrapper div{...} styles override specific ID styles

Tags: html, css

I have several div's nested inside a #wrapper div, like so

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="one"></div>
      <div id="two"></div>
      <div id="three"></div>
    </div>
```

I am styling all div's within the wrapper, but also want some specific styles for the interior divs. Like this for example.

```
#wrapper div{
   background-color: grey;
}

#one{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

instead of the background color for the #one div being blue, the #wrapper div styles override it and the background color is grey.

I know I can use !important, but doing that requires putting it on every style that I want to be different from the overriding styles, which could be many across multiple divs. There has to be a better way to do this right?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of specificity of the parent element with an id, you will need to create a higher specificity rule for your other div as such:

```
#wrapper div{
   background-color: grey;
}

#wrapper #one{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense, although I really wish the default function of the CSS didn't make this necessary. Seems out of place from the normal cascade. It probably has higher level applications than anything I'm working with yet though.

Comment: You can try adding classes, if you can of course, and this will allow you to style with CSS in a more "normal" way. This is a good read if you want to understand specificity more: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

You can just override it by provide more specific rule for your `#one` div like this:

```
#wrapper #one{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dZ8KX/2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks for the fiddle too